# HTML List Filtering Not Filtering Correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting up a filtering system on my website with buttons that filter images below and I have come across a problem. When I try to filter by lets say "Bob" it will also show results under "Bobby".

I am using [w3schools'](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp) method. Below is the code I am using

```
  <button class="button" onclick="filterSelection('all')">All</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="filterSelection('bob')">Bob</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="filterSelection('bobby')">Bobby</button>

  <div class="column bob">Bob</div>
  <div class="column bobby">Bobby</div>
```

and my javscript

```
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("is-active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" is-active", "");
    this.className += " is-active";
  });
}
```

Comment: When you search for bob, it also matches bob in `'bob'by`. To avoid this issue either you should have unique class names or try the following solution by Andu Andrici

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
(x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1)
```

to

```
((" "+x[i].className+" ").indexOf(" "+c+" ") > -1)
```

It adds a space around the entire className string, and also around the class itself.

This will not allow that searching for 'bob' to return positive for 'bobby' :)

Comment: This does work; however, trying to sort by all is no longer functioning. Do you know how I could go about fixing this?

Comment: When sorting all, simply loop over all items and display them. Include that in an if/else statement, like if (sort="all") { code to show all } else { run the search query and diplay only the relevant ones }